# script informix para consulta

Tags: sql, informix

Tengo las siguientes tabla en informix con los siguientes campos:

```
anioexp, año expediente
cvecodexp, tipo de expediente
numexp, numero de expediente
fcap, fecha de captura
voz, voces (campo de texto)
```

un numero de expediente puede llegar a tener mas de una "voz" lo que quiero saber si me ayudan es como hacer el query para que pueda tener en una sola consulta me concatenen en un solo campo todas las voces que pueden llegar a tener un mismo expediente separados por ","

gracias

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: Lo que usted necesita es una [*Función de Agregación Definida por Usuario*](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/12.10?topic=SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.udr.doc/ids_udr_191.htm)

Comment: podrias ser mas especifico

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo usar una función agregada, estilo sum o count, que concatena los valores de la columna. (ej:en mysql se llama group_concat)
Este tipo de función no existe aun en informix pero la puedes crear tu.
Aquí te explican como...
[group_concat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715350/show-a-one-to-many-relationship-as-2-columns-1-unique-row-id-comma-separate)